# Duplicate nth value from list

Tags: list, prolog

Fairly new to Prolog, I'm trying to implement a recursive rule `duplicate_nth(N,L1,L2)` which takes a 1-based index `N`, a list `L1` and duplicates the Nth value of `L1` and returns it in a list `L2`.

Sample use:

```
?- duplicate_nth(1, [2,3,4], X).
X = [2,2,3,4].                  % expected result
```

My current code is:

```
duplicate_nth(N,[H|T],L2) :- 
    N = 1,                      % Is `N` equal to 1?    
    append([H],[H|T],L2).       % If so, prepend `H` to `[H|T]`
duplicate_nth(N,H|T,L2) :-
    N > 1,
```

This works if `N = 1`. It will not, however, work if `N > 1` and I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: You don't really need append in your first clause. Any time you see `append([X], List, Result)` it's the same as `Result = [X|List]`. In this case, `[H]` append `[H|T]` is `[H|[H|T]]` which is the same as `[H,H|T]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly all functions on lists have the same structure. A base case:

```
function(FixedValues,List1,List2) :-
    !.
```

Where `List2` is written in function of `List1` and `FixedValues` is a set of parameters that is grounded.

And an inductive case:

```
function(Values,[H|T],[H2|T2]) :-
    other_function(H,H2), %transform H into H2
    ValuesNext is Values-1, %or some other function
    function(ValuesNext,T,T2).
```

The `!` is a "cut" and prevents Prolog to execute other predicate definitions if the conditions of the first one are met.

---

Applied to this problem, try:

```
duplicate_nth(1,[H|T],[H,H|T]) :- %base case
    !.

duplicate_nth(N,[H|T],[H|T2]) :- %inductive case
    N1 is N-1,
    duplicate_nth(N1,T,T2).
```

---

In most cases you need to make the program safer, since `N` might be out of bounds (less than or equal to zero, or larger than the length of the list.)

In that case, add:

```
duplicate_nth(_,[],[]).
```

Comment: There's no need for the cut if you add `N > 1` to the recursive ("inductive") case

Comment: True, but that will decrease the performance of the predicate. Because Prolog calls predicates from top to bottom, it can already know when calling the first predicate that it shouldn't call the second. But there is indeed nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: Great answer, code worked and you explained some concepts better to me than some books could.

Answer (score 2):

No need to worry about implementing recursive predicate(s) the right way!

Simply delegate the "recursive part" to [`same_length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=same_length/2), [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue), and [`length/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue):

```
duplicate_nth(N,Xs0,Xs1) :-                    % index `N` is 1-based
   same_length([_|Xs0],Xs1),
   Suffix = [X|_],
   append(Prefix,Suffix,Xs0),
   length([_|Prefix],N),
   append(Prefix,[X|Suffix],Xs1).
```

Sample query:

```
?- N   = 1, 
   Xs0 = [a,b,c,d], 
   duplicate_nth(N,Xs0,Xs1).
  N = 1, Xs0 = [a,b,c,d], Xs1 = [a,a,b,c,d]    % only solution
; false.
```

Let's generalize above query and see the solution set grow!

```
?- Xs0 = [a,b,c,d],
   duplicate_nth(N,Xs0,Xs1).
  N = 1, Xs0 = [a,b,c,d], Xs1 = [a,a,b,c,d]    % (same solution as before)
; N = 2, Xs0 = [a,b,c,d], Xs1 = [a,b,b,c,d]    % (new solution)
; N = 3, Xs0 = [a,b,c,d], Xs1 = [a,b,c,c,d]    % (new solution)
; N = 4, Xs0 = [a,b,c,d], Xs1 = [a,b,c,d,d]    % (new solution)
; false.
```

Note that `duplicate_nth/3` also works when used "in the other direction".

```
?- Xs1 = [a,b,b,c,d,d,e],
   duplicate_nth(N,Xs0,Xs1).
  N = 2, Xs1 = [a,b,b,c,d,d,e], Xs0 = [a,b,c,d,d,e]
; N = 5, Xs1 = [a,b,b,c,d,d,e], Xs0 = [a,b,b,c,d,e]
; false.
```

Last, let's run the most general query!

```
?- duplicate_nth(N,Xs0,Xs).
  N = 1, Xs0 = [_A],          Xs = [_A,_A]
; N = 1, Xs0 = [_A,_B],       Xs = [_A,_A,_B]
; N = 2, Xs0 = [_A,_B],       Xs = [_A,_B,_B]
; N = 1, Xs0 = [_A,_B,_C],    Xs = [_A,_A,_B,_C]
; N = 2, Xs0 = [_A,_B,_C],    Xs = [_A,_B,_B,_C]
; N = 3, Xs0 = [_A,_B,_C],    Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_C]
; N = 1, Xs0 = [_A,_B,_C,_D], Xs = [_A,_A,_B,_C,_D]
...
```

Fair enumeration "out-of-the-box"? Perfect!